# IONIC 3 InAppBrowser executeScript

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using [this native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/in-app-browser/) to open a InAppBrowser. Also I want to inject a css and/or JS in that page, as in that page mentioned, I should use below code for css inject but it doesn't work:

```js
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
   browser.insertCSS({ code: "body{color: red;" });
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript with below syntax

```
let promise = browser.executeScript({
            code: '(function() {if(functionname) { return functionname(); }}())'
 });
```

This will return promise

```
 promise.then((values) => {
    // process values here
 });
```

where browser is instance of your inappbrowser for example -

```
const browser = this.iab.create('url', "_blank", this.options);
```

Comment: Yes, can you share you some more details about your code?